# cloud foundry - 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: rest, cloud-foundry

I'm using Cloud Foundry v2. Trying to make REST call with ~12MB body size to one of my apps, and getting error 413 Request Entity Too Large with the following headers:

```
X-Cf-Requestid    c80a7e06-7102-459e-721a-251189596ece
Date              Sun, 07 Jun 2015 08:20:45 GMT
Content-Length    0
Content-Type      text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

What is the default body size limit in cloud foundry? How to configure it?

Answer (score 1):

Discovered as Netty's limitation.
Default is 10MB, but can easily be changed by calling setMaxRequestSize on NettyJaxrsServer instance.

Answer (score -1):

Consider asking this question on mailing lists - `cf-bosh.lists.cloudfoundry.org` for BOSH related topics or `cf-dev.lists.cloudfoundry.org` for CF related topics or `cf-lattice.lists.cloudfoundry.org` for Lattice related topics. The Cloud Foundry community is highly responsive there and you will probably get an answer fast.

Also, there is UI, where you can view all the existing mailing threads. These are links for the [first](http://cf-bosh.70367.x6.nabble.com/), [second](http://cf-dev.70369.x6.nabble.com/) and [third](http://cf-lattice.70370.x6.nabble.com/) lists accordingly.